# Call a method of generic class instance passed as object

Tags: c#, generics, methods, casting

I have a generic class containing a special collection. An instance of this collection is passed to a method as object. Now I have to call one of the generic class' methods. The problem I see is that I don't know which type the items in the collection are of so that I can't cast before using the property.

```
public class MyGenericCollection<T>: ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
{
  public bool MyProperty
  {
    get
    {
      // do some stuff and return
    }
  }
}

public bool ProblematicMethod(object argument)
{
  MyGenericCollection impossibleCast = (MyGenericCollection) argument;
  return impossibleCast.MyProperty;
}
```

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, it may be worth adding an interface containing all your non-generic members:

```
public IHasMyProperty
{
    bool MyProperty { get; }
}
```

then make the collection implement it:

```
public class MyGenericCollection<T>: ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>,
    IHasMyProperty
```

then take an `IHasMyProperty` in your method:

```
public bool ProblematicMethod(IHasMyProperty argument)
{
    return argument.MyProperty;
}
```

or keep taking `object`, but cast to the interface:

```
public bool ProblematicMethod(object argument)
{
    return ((IHasMyProperty)argument).MyProperty;
}
```

In other cases you could have a non-generic abstract base class which your generic class extends, but in this case you're already deriving from a generic class (`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>`) which removes that option.

Comment: `IHasMyProperty`, true, but `ICanHasCheezburger`?  http://icanhascheezburger.com/

Answer (score 1):

I like the interface Jon suggest, but you may also try casting it a different way:

```
public bool ProblematicMethod(object argument) 
{ 
  MyGenericCollection impossibleCast = argument as MyGenericCollection;
  if( impossibleCast != null )
    return impossibleCast.MyProperty; 

  // Other castings?
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this too but I think I would have to add some extra magic to be able to cast to a non generic type MyGenericCollection instead of MyGenericCollection<T>.